# How to get tempo to work?

Tags: text-editing

I am trying to get some simple snippets to work with tempo, but I can’t get it to do anything. I am currently using this code, which I partly copied:

```lisp
(require 'tempo)
(defvar c++-tempo-tags nil
  "Tempo tags for C++ mode")

(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook #'(lambda ()
                 (tempo-use-tag-list 'c++-tempo-tags)
                 ))

(tempo-define-template "c-include"
               '("#include <" r ".h>" > n
             )
               "inc"
               "Insert a #include <> statement"
               'c++-tempo-tags)
```

Now, as far as I understand tempo, I would expect it to insert the include snippet when I type "inc" and then call the command `tempo-complete-tag`. However, this just causes Emacs to freeze for 2 seconds, but nothing is inserted.

I am not sure if this is how tempo is even supposed to work, because there seems no simple example to be available anywhere.

Please don’t suggest yasnippets, that package seems abandoned and just generates error messages for me.

Comment: Your code works as you expected it to for me in Emacs 28.2.  Try with `emacs -Q` ?

Comment: See also https://www.lysator.liu.se/~davidk/elisp/ (per the tempo.el commentary).

Comment: @phils You are right, it works after a restart of Emacs. I should have tested this before submitting this question.